# Is there a difference in these javascript include definitions

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Both include the same files. Both works but is there any advantage favoring the one over the other?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought that the '~/' syntax is a .NET directive and does no good outside of a .NET function call or a tag with the runat="server" attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case the Url.Content converts a relative path to an application absolute path

In the second case the string is considered a literal and outputted link will contain the ~/. Which in most cases would not work because it will look for a folder named ~ under the current directory.

But in asp.net mvc 4 the razor viewengine will see the ~/ and do the Url.Content for you automatically.

http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2

Comment: Correct! Pre MVC2/razor 2, @Url.Content was required when the application did not run at the root level (for example in IIS, not in Cassini or IIS Express). As you mention, MVC 4/Razor 2 fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a minimal amount of more work in the first, because the compiler finds `@Url.Content` and calls that function.

The end result is the same, but I think there are 2-3 more steps more in the first.  All of that will happen in [milli-nano]seconds, though.

Comment: Pre MVC2/razor 2, @Url.Content was required when the application did not run at the root level (for example in IIS, not in Cassini or IIS Express). Razor 2 fixes this.

Comment: That might be true, but it is still a server directive used for interpolation.