# Tilde Slash Paths Not Working in MVC 4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

As [I understand it](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2), a plain ol' "~/foo" path is supposed to work like @Url.Content("~/") in MVC 4. However, I'm trying to do this and getting many broken paths -- the tilde is still there when the HTML is output.

So, for example, I have this path in /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And the HTML delivered looks like this:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I'm pretty sure I have this running as an MVC 4 project, too. The following stuff's in the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

...and at this point, I'm not sure what to look for next. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you are still using Razor 1, [not Razor 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10194146/175679)

Comment: Can you try creating a MVC 4 Internet application and try this feature? Maybe you are not using Razor 2 as @SilverNinja also mentioned if you just changed the reference to MVC 4.

Comment: I tried creating a new MVC 4 application and the feature still fails. Going to try reinstalling MVC 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstalling MVC 4 (RC) using the standalone installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29935) solved this problem for me. I still don't understand what caused the problem, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 17):

This could be as a result of [a bug in Razor V2](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/933), where an apostrophe / single quote in an HTML comment breaks resolution of `~` paths.

The workaround is to use Razor comments instead of HTML comments.  I.e., replace `<!-- Here's your comment-->` with `@* Here's your comment *@`.

Sorry this is a long shot, as I've no idea if you have HTML comments, let alone ones containing single quotes.

Comment: I just got hung up on this too. The page I was working on had an html comment with a single " in it. Deleting the " or adding a second " to the comment fixes the issue.

Comment: This was the cause of mine:  --->   Extra dash on closing comment at top of page.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that you are still running Razor 1 (`MvcWebRazorHostFactory` is < 4.0).

Verify the web.config in your **Views** folder looks like this...

```xml
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: If you are using MVC 4, you should be able to get [resource bundling working](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx). Can you try bundling your CSS?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when I cut and paste some example code into a view.
Turned out I had the wrong type of tilde!

```
@{
Layout = "∼/Views/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
}
```

vs

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Subtly different - sod to find

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was only related to SVG image types. Solved it by adding the following to the project's web.config file (*not* the web.config used by the views, MVC4).

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

For MVC 5 and Razor 3, the problem for me turned out to be an extra quote character in an html element that came before (long before!) the img tag:

```
<div class="foo""> <!-- note the extra quote character here ugh -->
...
</div>
...
<img src="~/images/an-image.png" />
```

The above problem caused razor to ignore the tilde (~), giving it to the browser as-is / not transformed.  Took me forever to find the problem, which I eventually found by moving the img tag to the top of the file and discovering it worked fine there, and then doing a divide-and-conquer approach to narrow down the spot in the *.cshtml file where it stopped working.

I hope this post saves someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about `href=` and not which `< tag >`
Examples:

```
< img src="@Url.Content("Images/someImage.jpg")"/>
< a href="@Url.Content("Home/About")" >click here< /a>
```

Its ok to nest `@` inside other `@section {}`

Comment: The downvote may have been because this syntax should no longer be required.  
http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2

Comment: Scott is right, but technically Peter's solution will still work if you're accidentally on Razor 1.  Better to just install Razor 2, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me was turning off Meleze.web HTML Minification.