# Scripts in Bundles are rendering with ~/Scripts and so its not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I have a MVC application that developed partially by someone else. It works in that particular Machine.
When i run the application in my machine, I found the scripts in bundle are rendering with relative path.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

all the scripts rendering same way where as the CSS files are rendering good. I am using bundles this way.

**in BundleConfig.cs**

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/EMRMobileScript").Include (
  "~/MobileQuerys/js/jquery.js",
  "~/MobileQuerys/docs/_assets/js/jqm-demos.js"
  ));
```

**In _Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/EMRMobilecss")
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/EMRMobileScript")
```

**In browser console**

```
GET http://localhost:6326/~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Why its rendering with **~** ??

Comment: And have you defined a bundle for jQuery scripts in your `BundleConfig.cs`? Or have a directory named `Scripts` with `jquery-1.9.1.js` inside of it...

Comment: There is [a similar question here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853316/tilde-slash-paths-not-working-in-mvc-4) that might solve your issue.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie Everything is perfect and i found the solution.Anyway it was working in another machine. I had to uninstall MVC 4 and re-install the same. Now it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client doesn't know what the "~" sign means while the server does. It's just another char the you placed in a string.

When you add a relative src it will be "concated" to the current path, which is

`http://localhost:6326/`

and thats why you get this request:

`http://localhost:6326/~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js`

Now, when you use this line of code in the server:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/EMRMobilecss")
```

The server knows how to map the path(where ~ is the applications "root" directory).

In order to render the specifc bundle from your js, use this:

```
<script src='http://localhost:6326/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's running on the local host, it's a known bug that occurs. If IIS is running the application it more than likely is an issue with that. Have you tried just running this with just the MVC?

Otherwise there isn't really a work around for this when running it on IIS.