# Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC Not Loading Local bootstrap.css

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I installed bootstrap using nuget package manager and the css files are now in my /Content/ folder. However, when trying to reference them using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="∼/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

It doesn't work. But when referencing them using a CDN like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

It does work. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong as I have never had this problem before. I'm using an Empty template with MVC.

EDIT: After some playing around, I found that it was failing to load /%E2%88%BC/Content/bootstrap.css but after removing the tilda (~) it works fine. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler or F12 dev tools to see if it is attempting to download the file and failing?

Comment: Yes it's failing to download bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css. 404 not found.

Comment: Do any of the answers here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853316/tilde-slash-paths-not-working-in-mvc-4

Comment: I FINALLY figured out what the problem was. I'm reading an e-book for ASP.NET MVC and as the examples are big, I have to copy and paste (my fault, I know) and it turns out that the because the font is different in the book, it doesn't pick it up. So I just typed the ~ myself instead of copying the ∼ from the book. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: I think it is necessary to add the bundle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869907/adding-bootstrap-in-bundleconfig-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

This is not a correct path, it uses the tilda, which is used on the server when rendering links in server controls in asp.net.

Instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="∼/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("∼/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" />
```

Assuming that you are using Razor.

---

Alternatively, consider looking into style and script bundling that you get with new asp.net sites.  Can be very useful.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working. Breaks the application with "Compiler Error Message: CS1056: Unexpected character '∼'". My intellisense doesn't seem to like anything that I'm passing to the @Url.Content.

Comment: Doesn't work with passing the string in quotes either.

Comment: Sorry, missed the quotes.  Having the string passed in quotes works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "app.UseStaticFiles()" to Startup.cs worked for me:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Now only Bootsrap 3 works with local links in .Net. Terrible. :(  For 4, you must use CDN :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```